# Library database

Tags: text-processing, sed, database

I have a database of readers and I would like to lend them a book and write it into the database.

Example:

Reader

```
753     Leonardo DaVinci    davinci@gmail.com   321654987   Lended Books:

grep "Leonardo" database_readers.txt | sed  "s/\(.*\):/\1: Narnie/"
```

With this command I only output the line with book Narnie added at end of the line, but  how do I change the line in the file?

Thank for any advice

Comment: I don't mean add a line at the end of file, but change the line. Or if someone would give a solution to delete the line and add the new line with reader and new book added at the end of the line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sed -i -e '/Leonardo/ s/$/ Narnie/' database_readers.txt
```

This uses `sed`'s in-place edit option (`-i`) to search for all lines matching the regexp `Leonardo`, and replace the end-of-line anchor (`$`) with a single space and the word `Narnie`.  This effectively appends the `Narnie` to the end of the matching lines.

Be careful with the regexp search pattern - it's easy to match more lines than you were expecting.  Test first with:

```
sed -n -e '/Leonardo/ s/$/ Narnie/p' database_readers.txt
```

The `-n` option combined with the `p` at the end of the `s///` makes `sed` print out ONLY the lines that were changed.  Do **NOT** use this with `sed -i` unless you want to delete ALL unchanged lines from your file.

Anyway, if that prints out more lines than you were expecting then change `Leonardo` to `Leonardo DaVinci` or `^753[[:space:]]\+` (assuming that the number at the beginning of the line is a unique ID), and try again until it changes only the line(s) you were expecting it to.

For anything more complicated than that, you may want to look into using `sqlite` (or even `mysql` or `postgresql`) rather than a flat text file.  Or use a language like `perl` which has many library modules for manipulating flat-file databases.